# Low Oracle Trigger Performance after 10 hours

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, triggers

We have AFTER trigger defined on INSERT in some table. We have seen that till 10 hours everything works fine, but after 10 hours INSERT query is taking time in minutes. We are inserting around 100 rows per second. We have seen that at oracle side some redo logs, undo segment extension and write wait is taking much of the time during the problem duration. But we have seen that undo segment extension limit is not reached but undo segment extension is taking time. undo table space is fine during that time.

So is it due to result of redo logs??

Comment: [dba.se] would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Do you have anything that shows that the performance problem has anything to do with the trigger?  With the redo logs?  With UNDO?  Or are you just guessing more or less at random?  If the entire system is slow, I'd start with an AWR/ Statspack report that tells you what's taking your time.  If a particular session is slow, I'd start with a session trace or an ASH report to show where the time is going.  If you don't know what is slow, it's highly unlikely that you'll be able to identify a solution.

Comment: Yes a particular session is slow. I will collect the information. But we have tried with disabling the trigger, then every thing works fine. but there would be less insert in that case.Can you please tell how I can enable session trace.

Comment: @sonutiwari - One good introduction would be this Tim Hall article http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof.php

Comment: Thanks Justin, I have run the AWR report, it shows that log file switch (checkpoint incomplete) takes around average wait 99729ms